# Return Cursor from Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, database-cursor

How can I return a cursor from stored procedure in MySQL?

Comment: returning from mysql to where?

Comment: Lets say it's returned to php I would like to know how that happens

Answer (score 2):

Simply: **Don't do it!**

Seriously: it's an indication that your design is flawed.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why.

Answer (score 0):

A cursor is a server side thing. You can't "return" this to a client.

Answer (score -1):

mysql doesn't support client-side cursors. they exist ONLY in stored procedures.